# Password checker (Boolean variables not changing value)

Tags: c

I am a beginner at C programming and I was trying to code a password checker, but the value of variable strength which is supposed to be 3 is only 2. So, I tried to print out the values for variables  upper, lower, number, and symbol. It turned out that variables number and symbol did not change its value to 1, which caused the problem.

How do I solve this, and why does the values of variable number and symbol not change?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int checkPassword(char*);

int main(void){
   int strength = checkPassword("Aardvark77");
    
    if(strength ==3)
      printf("STRONG");
    else if(strength ==2)
      printf("GOOD");
    else if(strength ==1)
      printf("ACCEPTABLE");
    else if(strength ==0)
      printf("WEAK");
      
return 0;
}

int checkPassword(char* password) {
char arrSymbol[12]={'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '+'};
int arrNumber[10]={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int strength=0, length, i, j, a, b, c, d;
bool upper=0, lower=0, number=0, symbol=0;

 length=strlen(password);
 
 if(length>=8)
  strength++;
 
 for(a=0; a<length; a++)
   for(b=0; b<10; b++){
     if(password[a]==arrNumber[b])
        number=1;
    }
    
 for(c=0; c<length; c++)
   for(d=0; d<12; d++){
     if(password[c]==arrSymbol[d])
        symbol=1;
    }
 
  for(i=0; i<length; i++){
    if(password[i]>='A' && password[i]<='Z')
        upper=1;
  }
     
  for(j=0; j<length; j++){
    if(password[j]>='a' && password[j]<='z')
        lower=1;
  }
  printf("%d %d %d %d", number, symbol, lower, upper);
  if(number || symbol)
    strength++;
  
  if(upper || lower)
   strength++;
   
return strength;
}
```

Comment: did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Your password contains characters, but you are comparing it to `arrNumber` which contains numbers. You need to either fill it with characters (such as `'0', '1'...`) or convert them on the fly.

Comment: I haven't stepped through everything, but I find the lack of curly-braces enclosing most of your loops and conditionals to be very dangerous and prone to error.

Comment: I do see that you explicitly set `strength = 1;` if you've got a number or symbol, rather than incrementing strength.  That's probably your issue.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you. the problem with boolean variable number was fixed, but the problem with the variable symbol not changing values is still there. How do I fix that?

Comment: as an aside, there are functions that exist like `isdigit()` `isupper()` `islower()`, and `ispunct()`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Sorry was not able to edit that one that should have been strength++; . Anyway, the problem with variable symbol is still there though.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Oh I see :). I was not aware of those functions thanks :).

Comment: `"Aardvark77"` does not contain any "symbols".

Comment: Here is the full list of the character classification functions: https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha . And you really should be able to get away with a *single* loop.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh okay, I forgot that was the input. Thank you so much guys. :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks bro, sorry I'm really a beginner, so I am not that familiar with programming. Thanks again guys :).

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere.  I've seen worse code.

Comment: you can also reuse your loop index variables, each `for` loop doesn't need a unique one. Better yet, define them in the `for` loop as long as their scope is contained to the loop, `for (int i=0; ... `, I think that's been supported for a while now.

Comment: @yano I believe it was introduced in C99, so 23 years?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Wow C99 growing up, we're hittin the pub tonight

Answer (score 1):

First `bool` datatype needs to include `<stdbool.h>` header.

Your program can be changed to be more reliable by applying comments.

In a `for...loop` you can define an index like:

```
int a;
for (a=0;a<10;a++)
```

but this can be written more simply in this form:

```
for (int a=0;a<10;a++)
```

You can use library function like `isalpha()` and `isdigit()`.

See more from standard [<ctype.h>](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/ctype_h.htm) library.

In loops after finding the first desired "thing" use `break` to stop iteration.

`if...else` expressions can be replaced with a `switch...case`.

At last, for better output add a `\n` for each `printf()`.

**the code so far**

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int checkPassword(char *);

int main(void) {

  int strength = checkPassword("Aardvark77");

  switch (strength) {
    case 3:    printf("STRONG\n");    break;
    case 2:    printf("GOOD\n");    break;
    case 1:    printf("ACCEPTABLE\n");    break;
    case 0:    printf("WEAK\n");    break;
    default:    break;
  }
  return 0;
}

int checkPassword(char *password) {

  char arrSymbol[13] = {'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^',
                        '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '+'};
  int strength = 0, length = 0;
  bool upper = 0, lower = 0, number = 0, symbol = 0;

  length = strlen(password);

  if (length >= 8)
    strength++;

  for (int a = 0; a < length; a++) {
    if (isdigit(password[a])) {
      number = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  for (int a = 0; a < length; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 12; b++) {
      if (password[a] == arrSymbol[b]) {
        symbol = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (isupper(password[i])) {
      upper = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (islower(password[i])) {
      lower = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  printf("number: %d\nsymbol: %d\nlowercase: %d\nuppercase: %d\n", number,
         symbol, lower, upper);

  if (number || symbol) {
    strength++;
  }
  if (upper || lower) {
    strength++;
  }

  return strength;
}
```